# Remove an specific element from a list and create a new nested list

Tags: python, list

I want to create a nested list containing lists from a single large list which has 5k+ elements.
Here is my existing list,

```
x = [925.5, 310.0, 911.5, 1492.0,
 1658.5,
 1642.5,
 747.0,
 324.5,
 831.5,
 1173.0,
 1009.5,
 1830.5,
 1376.0,
 0.0,
 749.0,
 1492.0,
 1834.5,
 913.5,
 920.5,
 1658.5,
 1644.5,
 303.0,
 833.0,
 1172.5,
 1381.0,
 1008.5,
 1680.5,
 1341.5,
 0.0,
 749.0,
 1492.0,
 1834.5,
 913.5,
 920.5,
 1658.5,
 1645.0,
 303.5,
 833.0]
```

and I want a list like this (when a zero comes it will be removed and give me a new list onwards).

```
x_new = [[925.5, 310.0, 911.5, 1492.0, 1658.5, 1642.5, 747.0, 324.5, 831.5, 1173.0, 1009.5, 1830.5, 1376.0],[749.0, 1492.0, 1834.5, 913.5, 920.5, 1658.5, 1644.5, 303.0, 833.0, 1172.5, 1381.0, 1008.5, 1680.5, 1341.5],[749.0, 1492.0, 1834.5, 913.5, 920.5, 1658.5, 1645.0, 303.5, 833.0]]
```

Comment: What is your question about this task?

Comment: can you please share with us some code you tried and what issue you are facing with that code? we can help you in fixing it

Answer (score 3):

```
x_new = []
nested = []
for i in x:
    if i != 0:
        nested.append(i)
    else:
        x_new.append(nested)
        nested = []
if nested:
    x_new.append(nested)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me.

Comment: This won't append the last set of values. You have to add `x_new.append(nested)` after and outside the for loop

Comment: thanks for your comment